# $ path environmental variable for Azure Portal Account Creation

Tags: azure, powershell, csv

This is probably a beginner's question for powershell, but I have a powershell command that will pick up on a CSV saved onto my desktop and run it. To be specific, it will do an account creation for Azure portal and the CSV has the new accounts' data. My team will be using this, and we don't have the same path. How do I change my path to an environmental variable that will pick up on the CSV for them? My coworker suggested $ path but I don't understand how it works. Command is below:

Import-Csv -Path C:\Projects\AccountCreationTest.csv | foreach {New-MsolUser -DisplayName $*.DisplayName -FirstName $*.FirstName -LastName $*.LastName -UserPrincipalName $*.UserPrincipalName} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Projects\outputazure.csv

I also want to be able to add "Connect-MsolService" to the beginning of this as this script won't run without connecting to Azure. How can I make this all into one simple step and not have to copy paste this command each time into powershell?

Comment: Why _don't_ you have same path? Put the files on a network share and use UNC path to access it. Ask your coworker what was meant with `$ path`. Powershell can access system path via `$env:path`, but that's used to look for executables, not data files.

Comment: I believe because before this script gets executed the person has to use "Connect-MsolService" command on powershell to access the Azure module. So he's saying make it all in one step? and to not have to find the script to copy paste each time

Comment: Please _ask your coworker to explain_ with more details. It's a fool's errand to ask from strangers in the Interwebs what your coworker might or might not mean.

Comment: Okay so what they want is for this script to be run but for us to be able to input the directory of the csv each time, because it will be different each time. So my script except instead of where it has the CSV directory, to pick up on the directory the person running the command inputs at the end or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following cmd to the beginning of the script.

```
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$path
  )
```

Then you could use `Import-Csv -Path $path` to import it. It will require the user who runs the script to enter the full path of the csv file.

Comment: Hi, thank you this worked, however I was wrong in what I needed for this. I need this script to be run but for us to be able to input the directory of the csv each time, because it will be different each time. So my script except instead of where it has the CSV directory, to pick up on the directory the person running the command inputs at the end

Comment: @shaheed313 Sorry but what do you mean by "pick up on the directory the person running the command inputs at the end"?